# Run a loop on unique group by values from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe on which I have applied a 'group by'. I want to run a loop on all the unique Creative values for each Advertiser ID (. What is the most efficient way to do that?)

Here are the lines that I wrote to do a group by -

```
import pandas as pd


filedf = pd.read_csv('C:\Mayank_Data\Test(New)\Creative Analysis\Test File for download v2.csv')
dataframe2 = filedf.groupby('Advertiser ID')['Creative'].apply(list).to_frame()
```

[image]

This is how my dataframe looks like after I applied group by

[image: This is how my dataframe looks like after I applied group by]

Comment: Please supply your code, and some examples. This will make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: Great! Could you supply some of the content from your .csv as we do not have access to that :)

Comment: Done, but had to hide data as it is confidential :) But All I need is to run a loop on unique value for 1,2 and 3
1 -> a,b
2 ->c,d
3 ->e,f,g

Comment: Please don't post image as data or code. Create a copy and paste-able sample instead.